# How can I calculate the distance matrices if I have many data points with same coordinates

Tags: r, spatial

Please, excuse me as it seems that this is very simple problem but I could not able to solve it. I am trying to estimate the spatial autocorrelation in my data set. 
Here is a small example of my data:

```
Lat Lon
33.32   34.23
36.33   65.34
67.43   56.43
67.43   56.43
54.34   56.43
44.56   56.43
```

When I use the `dist` command to calculate the distance matrix, there are 'inf' values in the matrix. I am using `Moran.I` test to estimate the spatial autocorrelation. But it gives me an error 'missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed'. How can I overcome this problem.

Comment: Could you please show us your call to `dist` and your call to `Moran.I`? Knowing what vector you're passing to argument `x` in `Moran.I` (assuming you used the function `Moran.I` from package `ape`) and what `method` you chose for `dist` will help answering you. I tried `Moran.I(x=rnorm(6),weight=as.matrix(dist(dat)))` (`dat` being the set of coordinates you provided) and it didn't result in an error.

Comment: Distance<- as.matrix(dist(cbind(dat$Lon,dat$Lat)))
Disatnce<- 1/Distance
diag(Distance_inv)<- 0
lm1<- lm (y ~ x + z, data=dat)
Moran.I(lm1$res,Distance_inv)

Comment: Additionally [this tutorial](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/morans_i.htm) might help you.

Comment: @plannapus, I used the exact same tutorial but there is some problem...

Comment: if you end up with `Inf` values because you take the inverse of your distance matrix (thus creating a bunch of 1/0) you can correct for it with the following: `is.infinite(Distance) <- 0`. This is for that specific reason that they used (in the tutorial) the line `diag(ozone.dists.inv) <- 0` I think, because, with the exception of the diagonal they didn t have any other 0.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will try it and let you know